# How to diagnose a "Error syncing pod" pod on Kuberentes?

Tags: kubernetes

I've got a deployment that has a pod that is stuck at :

The `describe` output has some sensitive details in it, but the events has this at the end:

```
  ...
  Normal   Pulled                 18m (x3 over 21m)  kubelet, ip-10-151-21-127.ec2.internal  Successfully pulled image "example/asdf"
  Warning  FailedSync             7m (x53 over 19m)  kubelet, ip-10-151-21-127.ec2.internal  Error syncing pod
```

What is the cause of this error? How can I diagnose this further?

---

It seems to be repulling the image, however it's odd that it's `x10 over 27m` I wonder if it's maybe reaching a timeout?

```
  Warning  FailedSync             12m (x53 over 23m)  kubelet, ip-10-151-21-127.ec2.internal  Error syncing pod
  Normal   Pulling                2m (x10 over 27m)   kubelet, ip-10-151-21-127.ec2.internal  pulling image "aoeuoeauhtona.epgso"
```

Answer (score 3):

The **kubelet** process is responsible for pulling images from a registry.

This is how you can check the `kubelet` logs:

```
$ journalctl -u kubelet
```

More information about images can be found in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/).

Comment: journalctl -u kubelet ie kubelet logs on master on the node where pod is running ?

Comment: on node running failed pod:Dec 30 08:02:31 ip-172-21-56-148 kubelet[1568]: E1230 08:02:31.443574    1568 pod_workers.go:182] Error syncing pod 339e7f04-2a9b-11ea-a92d-024aeca0bafc ("gatekeeper-1225751150-61pf1_cog-prod01(339e7f04-2a9b-11ea-a92d-024aeca0bafc)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "gatekeeper" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=gatekeeper pod=gatekeeper-1225751150-61pf1_cog-prod01(339e7f04-2a9b-11ea-a92d-024aeca0bafc)"

Comment: from this log how to figure out the exact reason for Error syncing pod?

Comment: That error means Pod’s container is unable to start. It’s time to check container logs. `kubectl logs podname -c containername —previous` or using similar docker command on the node where pod is scheduled.

Comment: admin@ip-$ kubectl  logs  -n cog-prod01     slotmachine-1697-v9gbp    -f
09:47:30.331 [main] INFO  org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Fetching config from server at: http://configservice:8888
09:47:33.504 [main] WARN  org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://configservice:8888/slotmachine/cog,cog-prod01": No route to host (Host unreachable); nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)

Comment: this pod is not able to connect to that configservice but others are able to connect, only 1/5 pods is not able to connect to this service

Comment: It’s not related to original question any more. Please write another question. Please also provide information about existing Services and pod DNS settings. I’d recommend to put sleep command to the pod after original command and exec to the pod for investigation when you see that error in logs again.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the logs of your pod:

```
kubectl logs pod-id
```

More information here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/

Comment: Would this not just show the logs from the container? The container doesn't even get started however.

Comment: I can't test this as I'm not able to get to that state again.